# Publish same message on 2 channels in Pubnub

Tags: android

I am integrating pubnub to send/ receive message. I want to send same message on the two channels and I want the callback only at 1 channel no other channel. How can I approach that. I am using this code to publish the message on pubnub

```
  AppController.pubNub.publish()
            .channel(mychannel)// this is my 1st channel 
            .message(jsonObject)
            .async(new PNCallback<PNPublishResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(PNPublishResult result, PNStatus status) {
                    if (!status.isError()) {
                       Log.d("message", result.toString());
                    }
                }
            });
```

How can I publish same message on other channel here.
Any help will be really appreciated.Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way in the PubNub Android SDK to do what you're describing.

You could take the approach of creating two separate publishes and having a predefined function which you could call within the override. Similar to this.

```
public void message(String result){
    Log.d("message", result);
}
AppController.pubNub.publish()
        .channel(mychannel)// this is my 1st channel 
        .message(jsonObject)
        .async(new PNCallback<PNPublishResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(PNPublishResult result, PNStatus status) {
                if (!status.isError()) {
                   message(result.toString())
                }
            }
        });
```

If that is really not an option, the best thing would be to create a serverless function on the PubNub admin panel which listens to 1 channel. In that function you could have the multiple publishes and that serverless function could return the response it receives from the two other channels.